# how to apply css only to the generated canvas in html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

After taking different pieces of code from some places I've been able to put together a javascript that export a div to pdf using html2canvas, but I would like to define the css style only for the generated pdf and not for the actual web page, here's the code (and thanks):

```
<script src='Resources/js/html2canvas.js'></script>
<script src='Resources/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='Resources/js/jspdf.debug.js'></script>
<script lang='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function run()
 {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    pdf.addHTML($('#DocArea')[0], function () {
            pdf.save('$xmlid.pdf');
        });
};
</script>


<a onClick='run()' body{-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;}><img style='padding-right: 22px;' title='Generate PDF' 
src='Images/pdfdowna.png' height='30px' onmouseover=\"this.src='Images/pdfdownb.png';\" onmouseout=\"this.src='Images/pdfdowna.png';\"></a>


<div id='DocArea' style='background-color: white; font-size: 0.5em; letter-spacing: 1px;'>
```

**Update:**
In the meantime I have discovered the code for making html2canvas displays the background color, so here I update the code for the java script:

```
function run()
 {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    var options = {pagesplit: true, // render all pages
                background :'#FFFFFF',
                width: 1000
        };
    pdf.addHTML($('#DocArea')[0], 15, 15, options, function () {
            pdf.save('$xmlid.pdf');
        });
};
```

Comment: it's quite unclear what you are asking. Once exported through html2canvas, you've got a raster image, do you want the special css rules be applied into this image or on the displayed result (if any). For the former, apply the styles before exporting, export, then remove the styles. For the later, just add some className to the element that will contain the result of the export. Also, your markup is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry if I explained it badly, I don't want to apply the styles on the div rendering the web page, I want only to apply them at the raster image, how do I apply the styles before exporting and then remove them, and how is the markup incorrect? thanks...

Comment: you can just add some css rule in your stylesheet targeting some special class, e.g `.toBeExported{background-color:#FF00FF;}`. Before the call to `html2canvas()` method, add this class to the desired element (`myDiv.className+=' toBeExported'`) then in the callback of the `html2canvas` method, remove this class (`myDiv.className = myDiv.className.replace('toBeExported').trim()`) and voilà ! Your markup is incorrect because you are setting some `body{-webkit....` where should be set html attributes. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that expert, I tried some combinations, no success, I did add this to the css `#DocArea {background-color: #ffffff; font-size: 0.4em; letter-spacing: 1px;}` but when you say element I'm not sure if you mean in the javasc code or the div, and where is the callback , after the pdf.save? is it ok if I change to `style='body{-webkit...'` tnks

Comment: exemples are good to teach and take little time, thanks anyway :-(

Comment: https://parall.ax/products/jspdf here have some examples for jsPDF, you can click to combobox and see other examples. the examples are about font sizes, background etc.